# Concern on hosting OSQA/Django on GAE

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-admin, osqa

I'm going to build a website using [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net) which is built on Django (a famous framework of Python). I'll host this site to Google App Engine (GAE). I wonder if GAE has support all features of OSQA.?

I'm also new to web admin, so I don't know that I could use my own domain name (e.g abc.com) to point to my site hosted on GAE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm going to build a website using OSQA which is built on Django (a famous framework of Python). I'll host this site to Google App Engine (GAE). I wonder if GAE has support all features of OSQA.?

At GAE you don't have support for relational databases (unless you are a beta-tester for [CloudSQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/)). That means no admin, which is 90% of Django's sex-appeal.

[Django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) adds NoSQL database support to the ORM. This enables admin on GAE, but it is not fully compatible (Django-nonrel is almost Django but it is not 100% Django). Throw OSQA at it and see if it sticks - if so, you are probably good to go with GAE.

Other Django friendly [PaaS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service) worth a look:

- [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/)
- [Gondor](https://gondor.io/)
- [AppHosted](https://apphosted.com/)
- [Epio](https://www.ep.io/)

For my Django projects I like [Linode](http://www.linode.com/) VPS, but I used to work as Linux sysadmin before being a full-time developer - I'll give you my root account when you take it from my cold, dead hands :-). Jokes apart, I would wait CloudSQL before using GAE for Django stuff.

[ update 1 ]

> I'm also new to web admin, so I don't know that I could use my own domain name (e.g abc.com) to point to my site hosted on GAE?

You [can't use your naked domain](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#naked_domain) - `abc.com` is out, but [you can use `anything.abc.com`](http://code.google.com/intl/us-US/appengine/docs/domain.html). The FAQ suggests setting a redirect, which is easy enough. Note however that you won't be able to use your domain name with HTTPS at all on GAE - you are constrained to hideous URLs like `https://your_app_id.appspot.com`.

If you are on GAE, using [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html) for your domain makes a lot of sense, so you can have Gmail handling email for your domain as well. It is free for 10 email accounts and will handle email for your naked domain (email@abc.com).

Comment: Thanks. I'm clear on first point. How about the second one? Could I use my own domain name (e.g abc.com) to point to my site hosted on GAE? Sorry if this question is too basic.

Comment: @Density21.5: I've updated the answer to make this clear, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to http://appengine.google.com.
2. Choise your app.
3. Go to App setting.
4. Click to Add Domain in Domain Setting menu.
5. Add domain.

But domain must be registered at Google Apps (http://www.google.com/apps/intl/ru/business/index.html) :(

See http://code.google.com/intl/us-US/appengine/docs/domain.html for detail.